# Converting a date field to date time in formula

Tags: formula

I have a requirement to convert a date field to date time and the time should always display 00:00 AM. I tried the below formula

```
DATETIMEVALUE(Text(Created_date__c)&" "& "00:00:00")
```

where `Created_date__c` is a date field.

It returns '12/02/2019 11:00 AM'. As per the requirement, it should display '12/02/2019 00:00 AM'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DATETIMEVALUE() will set the time to Greenwich Mean Time (GMT), and then convert it to the time zone of the user viewing the record when it's displayed. [See Using Date, Date/Time and Time Values in Formulas](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=formula_using_date_datetime.htm) in the Salesforce Help for more information.

> There is no way to determine a user's time zone in a formula. If all
>   your users are in the same time zone, you can adjust the time zone
>   difference by adding or subtracting the time difference between the
>   users' time zone and GMT to your converted values. However, since time
>   zones can be affected by Daylight Saving Time, and the start and end
>   dates for DST are different each year, this is difficult to manage in
>   a formula. We recommend using Apex for transactions that require
>   converting between Date/Time and Text or Date values.

So, if you meet the criteria of not having to worry about DST and having all your users in the same time zone, you may be able to modify your formula so that the time accommodates the offset to GMT. Otherwise, you're better off using Apex for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a Date value to a Date/Time using the DATETIMEVALUE( date ) function. The time will be set to 12:00 a.m. in Greenwich Mean Time (GMT), and then converted to the time zone of the user viewing the record when it’s displayed. For a user located in San Francisco, DATETIMEVALUE( TODAY() ) returns 5:00 p.m. on the previous day (during Daylight Saving Time) rather than 12:00 a.m. of the current day.

Answer (score 0):

DATETIMEVALUE( text( DateField )+' '+'21:00:00') ---FieldValue date with specific date & time as 4 PM EST
OR
DATETIMEVALUE( text( Now() )+' '+'21:00:00') ----Today date with 4 PM EST
OR
DATETIMEVALUE(Now() + ' ' + '00:00:00')  ---- today date with specific time
OR
DATETIMEVALUE(Now())  ---- today date with 12:00 time

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).